# Why do I fill Integer.MAX_VALUE in Matrix

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, 2d, integer-overflow

This question is from LeetCode 174. Dungeon Game.

The code is able to run correctly.

But if I delete `for (int[] level : dp) Arrays.fill(level, Integer.MAX_VALUE);` , the code will fail.

Why the code couldn't run, if I delete `for (int[] level : dp) Arrays.fill(level, Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

```
class Solution {
    public int calculateMinimumHP(int[][] dungeon) {    
        int rows = dungeon.length;
        int cols = dungeon[0].length;
        int[][] dp = new int[rows + 1][cols + 1];

         for (int[] level : dp) Arrays.fill(level, Integer.MAX_VALUE);


        dp[rows][cols - 1] = 1;  
        dp[rows - 1][cols] = 1;

        for(int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            for(int j = cols - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                int min = Math.min(dp[i][j + 1] , dp[i + 1][j]) - dungeon[i][j];
                dp[i][j] = min <= 0 ? 1 : min; 
            }
        }

        return dp[0][0]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, anything_else) = anything_else`.

So a code to find a minimum in an array should start off with `min=MAX_VALUE` assuming that there must be a value smaller than that somewhere inside the array.

```
found_min=MAX_VALUE
for (int i=0 ; i<size ; ++i)
  found_min = min(arr[i], found_min)
```

The only way for this code to fail is when the array is empty, and then the returned `found_min` would stay `MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Sorry, my unclear explanation leads to misunderstanding. 
The code is able to run correctly.
But if I delete     "for (int[] level : dp) Arrays.fill(level, Integer.MAX_VALUE); "   , the code will fail.

Why the code couldn't  run, if I delete “for (int[] level : dp) Arrays.fill(level, Integer.MAX_VALUE);”

Comment: Because then they will be 0, and all of the positive numbers are larger than zero so the matrix cells will not be updated with the minimum values.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for using `Integer.MAX_VALUE` has to do with the following line:

```
int min = Math.min(dp[i][j + 1] , dp[i + 1][j]) - dungeon[i][j];
```

Without knowing the full logic of your code, it is clear that the call to `Math.min()` is trying to find the smaller of two points.  Assuming you only have assigned actual game data to one point, then whatever single value that were assigned would show up as the minimum.  This would also assume that you would never have game data as large as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @user85421 The logic might work, but then there would be no way to distinguish a `MAX_VALUE` which were there by default against one which actually represents game data.

Comment: Sorry, my unclear explanation leads to misunderstanding. The code is able to run correctly. But if I delete "for (int[] level : dp) Arrays.fill(level, Integer.MAX_VALUE); " , the code will fail. Why the code couldn't run, if I delete “for (int[] level : dp) Arrays.fill(level, Integer.MAX_VALUE);”